# Show that the operator $T' = \lambda Id - T$ is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $T: \mathbb{K^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^n$ a linear operator with characteristic polynomial $p_T(x) = (x- \lambda)^n$. Show that the operator $T' = \lambda Id - T$ is nilpotent.

My proof:

We knows that the minimal polynomial $m_T(x)$ divide $p_T(x)$, then $m_T(x) = (x-\lambda)^k,$ for some $k<n.$

Hence  $\hspace{0.2cm}$ $T' = \lambda Id - T$ we have $ \hspace{0.2cm} T= \lambda Id - T'  $ (is this correct?)

Therefore, $0= m_T(T) = (T-\lambda Id)^k =  (\lambda Id - T' - \lambda Id)^k = (-1)^kT'^k  \hspace{0.2cm} \Rightarrow 0 = T'^k . $

It's done?

Comment: Just change $T^{k}$ to $(-1)^{k}T'^{k}$ at  the end and you are fine.

Comment: ok, but the proof is correct?

Comment: yes, it is correct.